# Лёгкий и маленький сайтик на html и css. Подскажите, пожалуйста, лучшие практики

Tags: html, css, инспекция-кода

Всем привет , начал изучать  web-программирование , написал лёгкий и маленький сайтик с помощью css и html , укажите на ошибки или на моменты , которые можно укоротить или упростить.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%
}


/* styles for link*/

a {
  color: #38C0C6FF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}


/* styles for body*/

body {
  background-image: url(https://images.alphacoders.com/652/thumb-1920-65273.png);
  font-size: 1em;
}


/* styles for Header*/

header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 385px;
  background-image: url(http://tkani-astaseta.ru/image/cache/catalog/1bannnner1/bannerpustoj-1920x400.png);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 14px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  font-size: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  right: 100px;
}


/* Block Article*/

article {
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 550px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  width: 90%;
  border-color: #FFFF00FF;
  position: relative;
}


/*materials inside article*/

.materials,
.silk,
.cotton,
.polyester {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #C0C0C0FF;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: black;
}

.materials img {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  max-height: 295px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.silk {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 2%;
  border: 1px solid #FFFF00FF;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.cotton {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 2%;
  border: 1px solid #FFFF00FF;
  left: 569px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.polyester {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 2%;
  border: 1px solid #FFFF00FF;
  left: 1138px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/*hover for materials*/

.silk:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.cotton:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.polyester:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="aaa.css">
  <meta name="keywords" content="google , spam ">
  <meta name="discription" content="Good site">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:500&display=swap&subset=cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Текстиль</h1>
  </header>

  <article>
    <div class="materials">
      <a href="https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D1%91%D0%BB%D0%BA">
        <div class="silk">
          <img src="https://static6.depositphotos.com/1011833/560/i/450/depositphotos_5607955-stock-photo-purple-satin-or-silk-background.jpg">
          <p>Информация про шёлк</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA">
        <div class="cotton">
          <img src="http://fusion-of-styles.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/hlopok.jpg">
          <p>Информация про хлопок</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8D%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8B">
        <div class="polyester">
          <img src="https://protkan.com/wp-content/uploads/3b6aaf6c20e558df26bf3fddaddeccff_cr.jpg">
          <p>Информация про полиэстер</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```

https://codepen.io/SadxDarkness/pen/WNbPYKG

Comment: во-первых никогда не юзай position, иначе сайт будет подходить только под твой размер экрана

Comment: @Lofectr. а чем тогда пользоваться?

Comment: Часто для дизайна используют [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: использовать надо `flexbox` и `css grid` а `position` использовать только для позиционирования каких то компонентов но как основная сетка использовать нельзя

Comment: ну уж если ты доисторическое животное, то float

Comment: сожми css,уже 47%  сэкономишь! до остального надо учиться.

Answer (score -1):

Сам являюсь новичком и в поисках каких либо простеньких задачек, для набивания руки. Предлагаю свой вариант, и в общем то жду замечаний. Получилось где то на 40 строчек короче.

[Ссылка на CodePen](https://codepen.io/Mitr_rzn/pen/jOEdddO)

```css
body{
  background-image: url(https://images.alphacoders.com/652/thumb-1920-65273.png);
  font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-image: url(http://junior3d.ru/texture/%D0%A2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C/%D0%A2%D1%8E%D0%BB%D1%8C/%D1%82%D1%8E%D0%BB%D1%8C_72.jpg);
  font-size:2em;
}

nav a{
  color: yellow;
}

header{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
 background-image: url(http://tkani-astaseta.ru/image/cache/catalog/1bannnner1/bannerpustoj-1920x400.png);
  margin: auto;
}

h1{
  color: yellow;
  font-size:5em;
}

.tissue{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.material{
  max-width: 410px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.materialpic{
   max-height: 295px;
  max-width: 550px;
   border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.materialdesc{
  font-size: 3.5em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #BDBDBD;
  margin-top: -4px;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.material:hover{
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="aaa.css">
 <meta name="keywords" content="google , spam ">
 <meta name="discription" content="Good site">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:500&display=swap&subset=cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<nav>
  <a href="#">Продукция</a>
  <a href="#">Каталог</a>
  <a href="#">Контакты</a>
  <a href="#">О нас</a>
</nav>
<header>
  <h1>Текстиль</h1>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="tissue">
    <a href="#">
       <div class="material">
    <img src="https://static6.depositphotos.com/1011833/560/i/450/depositphotos_5607955-stock-photo-purple-satin-or-silk-background.jpg" alt="" class="materialpic">
    <div class="materialdesc">Информация
    про шелк
    </div>
  </div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div class="material">
    <img src="http://fusion-of-styles.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/hlopok.jpg" alt="" class="materialpic">
    <div class="materialdesc">Информация
    про хлопок
    </div>
  </div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div class="material">
    <img src="https://protkan.com/wp-content/uploads/3b6aaf6c20e558df26bf3fddaddeccff_cr.jpg" alt="" class="materialpic">
    <div class="materialdesc">Информация
    про полиэстер
    </div>
  </div>
    </a>
     
      
      
  </div>

</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: у меня вышло еще компактнее - убрал пустые строки!)))